# apt-mirror says it will download ~4GB but doesn't Download additional

Tags: apt, 20.04, repository, apt-mirror

I have ubuntu 20.04 running as a virtual machine on proxmox. I setup apt-mirror to help with our bandwidth issues at work (we have slow internet) to help update all the debian-based servers we have running. The repo works fine and without issues, I was just wondering why it still says it needs to download ~4GB, when it doesn't. Is this a known bug for apt-mirror? I've googled, duckduckgo, binged, whatever search engine you can think of, and every Question/Forum I've found either talks about it for a day, or is about something else entirely.

```
Downloading 375 index files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Thu May 20 10:13:09 2021
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Thu May 20 10:13:13 2021

Processing translation indexes: [TTTTTTTTTTTTT]

Downloading 596 translation files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Thu May 20 10:13:13 2021
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Thu May 20 10:13:20 2021

Processing DEP-11 indexes: [DDDDDDDDDDDDD]

Downloading 100 dep11 files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Thu May 20 10:13:21 2021
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Thu May 20 10:13:22 2021

Processing indexes: [PPPPPPPPlPPPPP]

3.1 GiB will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 110 archive files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Thu May 20 10:13:35 2021
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Thu May 20 10:13:35 2021

0 bytes in 0 files and 0 directories can be freed.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: having same issue...did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this script fixed my issue https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/113

Check the modified version of the script (scroll down)

**UPDATE** with details.

I used the script posted by rinnaz. Saved that as a *.sh file and ran it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# combined solutions for apt mirror from: https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/49,https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/102
# I had to create this file, in order to solve the issue of not downloading DEP-11 @2 files
# so all what I'm doing is running apt mirror manually, then downloading the other icon files every time
# Grep will grep the line starting with "set base_path"
# then we trim all extra white spaces
# then we cut the string by delimiter white space and take third value

dataFolder=$(grep -F "set base_path" /etc/apt/mirror.list | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f3)
echo "Base Folder path set in /etc/apt/mirror.list is: $dataFolder"
apt-mirror
echo 
echo -n "Do you want to Check MD5 Sum and Download Failed (auto Y in 5 seconds)? [Y/n]"
echo
read -t 5 answer
exit_status=$?
if [ $exit_status -ne 0 ] || [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ];then
    FAILEDPACKAGES=""
    echo "Reading and Checking MD5 checksum using file: $dataFolder/var/MD5"
    #cd $dataFolder/mirror
    rm -f FAILED_MD5.txt
    echo "Failed File will be stored in: $(PWD)/FAILED_MD5.txt"
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        #echo "Checking: $line"
        sum=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
        filename=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
        echo "$sum $dataFolder/mirror/$filename" | md5sum -c -
        RESULT=$?
        if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ];then
            echo "$dataFolder/mirror/$filename" >> FAILED_MD5.txt
            wget -O $dataFolder/mirror/$filename $filename
            echo "$sum $dataFolder/mirror/$filename" | md5sum -c -
            SUBRESULT=$?
            if [ $SUBRESULT -ne 0 ];then
                echo "Sorry failed checksum again for file: $dataFolder/mirror/$filename"
                $FAILEDPACKAGES+="$dataFolder/mirror/$filename      Failed again, sorry cannot help"
            fi
        fi
    done
```

Comment: thanks for adding the script!